# can not start the hadoop datanode hadoop 3.1.1 in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, datanode

I recently install the hadoop 3.1.1 to my computer in single cluster mode.after do all the configuration for hdfs-site.xml,yarn-site.xml,core-site.xml,mapred-site.xml and hadoop-env.sh following commands work without any error

*start-all.sh

*stop-all.sh

*start-dfs.sh

*start-yarn.sh

*hadoop namenode

*hadoop namenode -format

But i try to execute hadoop datanode it gives following error.

```
2018-12-12 14:20:16,129 WARN checker.StorageLocationChecker: Exception checking StorageLocation [DISK]file:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode
EPERM: Operation not permitted
at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.chmodImpl(Native Method)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.chmod(NativeIO.java:233)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:836)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$1.apply(ChecksumFileSystem.java:508)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$FsOperation.run(ChecksumFileSystem.java:489)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.setPermission(ChecksumFileSystem.java:511)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.mkdirsWithExistsAndPermissionCheck(DiskChecker.java:234)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDirInternal(DiskChecker.java:141)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:116)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.StorageLocation.check(StorageLocation.java:239)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.StorageLocation.check(StorageLocation.java:52)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.checker.ThrottledAsyncChecker$1.call(ThrottledAsyncChecker.java:142)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-12-12 14:20:16,131 ERROR datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain
org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Too many failed volumes - current valid volumes: 0, volumes configured: 1, volumes failed: 1, volume failures tolerated: 0
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.checker.StorageLocationChecker.check(StorageLocationChecker.java:220)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:2762)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2677)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2719)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2863)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:2887)
2018-12-12 14:20:16,133 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1: org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Too many failed volumes - current valid volumes: 0, volumes configured: 1, volumes failed: 1, volume failures tolerated: 0
2018-12-12 14:20:16,135 INFO datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at mihiran-Inspiron-5558/127.0.1.1
```

I followed so many previous stackover questions and answers to resolve this.But still unable to resolve

```
  hdfs-site.xml    



      <configuration>
                    <property>
                              <name>dfs.replication</name>
                              <value>1</value>
                   </property>
                   <property>
                             <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
                             <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode</value>
                   </property>
                   <property>
                             <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
                             <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode</value>
                   </property>
                   <property>
                             <name>dfs.permissions</name>
                             <value>false</value>
                   </property>
            </configuration>
```

here is the code for core-site.xml

```
     core-site.xml
  <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>fs.default.name</name>
                    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
                </property>       
  </configuration>
```

Here is the code for mapred-site.xml

```
    mapred-site.xml
    <configuration>
                  <property>    
                            <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>    
                            <value>localhost:54311</value>
                  </property>    
    </configuration>
```

Here is the code for yarn-site.xml

```
yarn-site.xml 
<configuration>
    <property>
          <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
          <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
   </property>
   <property>
          <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-    services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
          <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
   </property>

</configuration>
```

Comment: `Too many failed volumes`... Maybe `fsck` to fix your disks? But that would really be better asked at [unix.se]

Answer (score 2):

I resolve error by using this command

```
sudo chown -R  mihiran  /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode
```

Comment: By the way, I think you have followed a bad tutorial because as of Hadoop2, `mapred.job.tracker` doesn't need to be set

Comment: can you suggest a good tutorial for me.i followed so many youtube  tutorials for that.And also do i have to do changes for mapred-site.xml again.thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: I personally suggest starting with Hadoop's official Apache site because it will never be outdated for the version you are trying to setup